# How GA record page/session when click link which point to another domain

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

The problem is about how GA count the page per session when click on a cross domain link(already set cross domain tracking, but no tracking code on that domain).

I have a homepage on www.domainA.com, and there is a link, say,

```js
function jump(link){ 
  var windowprops = ''; 
  window.open(link, "menuPopup", windowprops); 
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="jump('www.domainB.com')">LINK</a>
```

When I set the link as above, and click on the link, the page per session will be recorded as 2.
However, when I change the

```html
<a href="www.domainB.com">LINK</a>
```

and other setting remains the same, the page per session will be recorded as 1.
I would like to know the mechanism of Google Analytics record the page per session.
By the way, I use Google Tag Manager to deploy Google Analytics.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but be advised that cross domain tracking will not work with your first example. Cross domain tracking works by "decorating" the href of yout outgoing link with the _ga parameter (which carries over the client id for the current session to the other domain), and since you do a javascript "redirect" (well, new window) this will not work (you'd need to retrieve the client id in your js function and append it as _ga parameter to the domainB url before you open the window).

Comment: Thanks Eike. Because I used Google Tag Manager to deploy GA, so I do not need to add my client ID, GTM will do that for me automatically. And actually the problem is not related to cross domain tracking. I am trying to ask how GA count page/session, because I got different results with two different ways to open the new window.